# How do I CloseHandle a handle that was converted to a FILE*?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

I am trying to redirect the output of a child process and return a `FILE*` to the parent.

I am essentially following the code example at [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The only modification is that i encapsulated the whole thing in a function and do

```
return _fdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t)g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, _O_RDONLY), "rb");
```

The problem is that I want to cleanup and `fclose` is throwing an error. Was I supposed to close handle after I did the `_fdopen`? How am I supposed to clean up here?

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) for `_open_osfhandle` states: "*To close a file opened with `_open_osfhandle`, call `_close`. The underlying handle is also closed by a call to `_close`, so it is not necessary to call the Win32 function `CloseHandle` on the original handle.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to close a file stream opened with `_fdopen` is to call `fclose`. If that's not working for you, then you have other problems.

Do not close the file descriptor after calling `_fdopen`. The documentation doesn't exactly say, but the `FILE` object owns that file descriptor and will close it when you call `fclose`. Likewise, the file descriptor owns the file handle, so you shouldn't call `CloseHandle`, either.

Answer (score 1):

May be quite late to answer, but just adding for reference. I looked into call stack of `fclose`, and it is actually making a call to `CloseHandle`

```
auto NThdl = CreateFileW(L"D:\\s.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    if (NThdl != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int iohdl = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t) NThdl, O_RDWR | O_BINARY);
        if (iohdl != 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            FILE *hLstFile = _wfdopen(iohdl, L"w+bc");
            fwrite("Bogus", 5, 1, hLstFile);

            fclose(hLstFile);            

            // Exception
            CloseHandle(NThdl);
        }
    }
```

[image]

And attempt to call `CloseHandle` after `fclose` would cause an exception saying that *Handle is invalid.*